# Bar plot with pgfplots: fit all bars on x axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart

This is the result so far:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.8}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    enlargelimits=0.15,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},
        anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    ylabel={\#mountainbikes},
    symbolic x coords={April, Mai, Juni, Juli, August},
    xtick=data,
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords align={vertical},
    ]
    \addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(April,0.36)};
    \addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(Mai,0.4)};
    \addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(Juni,0.5)};
    \addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(Juli,0.55)};
    \addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(August,0.52)};   
    \legend{\strut April, \strut Mai, \strut Juni, \strut Juli, \strut August}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

What I need help with: the x axis.

Comment: What do you mean by "fit all bars on x axis"?

Comment: @Roboticist as you can see on the pic: the x-axis label is only complete for April but not for the other months. And the very left and the very right bar are not on entirely in the picture (only like a third of them are shown).

Comment: Your code does not generate the image you have uploaded and returns some errors. Please supply an MWE.

Comment: Manually set a larger `enlargelimits`, for example `enlargelimits=.6`.

Answer (score 1):

With `pgfplots` such diagrams are ussuall drawn as follows:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17,   % the last version at time of the answer
             width=7cm}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    bar width = 4mm,              
    enlargelimits=0.15,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},
                  anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    ylabel={\#mountainbikes},
    symbolic x coords={April, Mai, Juni, Juli, August},
    xtick=data,
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords align={vertical},
    nodes near coords style={/pgf/number format/.cd, fixed, precision=2,
                             /tikz/.cd, font=\scriptsize},
    ]
\addplot    coordinates {(April,0.36) (Mai,0.4) (Juni,0.5) (Juli,0.55) (August,0.52)};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you like different colors for each month, than one possible solution using `pgfplots` package is make `\xtick` empty and instead them use `\legend`:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17,  
             width=7cm}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    bar width = 4mm,             
    enlarge x limits=0.8,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.05)},
                  anchor=north,legend columns=-1,
                  /tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=3pt},
                  /tikz/.cd, font=\footnotesize},
    ylabel={\#mountainbikes},
    xtick=\empty,
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords align={vertical},
    nodes near coords style={/pgf/number format/.cd, fixed, precision=2,
                             /tikz/.cd, font=\scriptsize},
    ]
\addplot    coordinates {(1,0.36)};
\addplot    coordinates {(2,0.4)};
\addplot    coordinates {(3,0.5)};
\addplot    coordinates {(4,0.55)};
\addplot    coordinates {(5,0.52)};
    \legend{April, Mai, Juni, Juli, August}
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is the color sequence previously set or automated in the latter case?

Comment: @BlackBird, used are default colors. You can overwrite them with `color=...` in each `\addtplot` or define own list of used colors.